# Remote Debug Website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, debugging

Is there a way to remotely debug a website?

I've just finished putting together a website that has some jquery animations. The site works fine on every machine/configuration I've tested it on.

One of the people the site needs to work for, however, reports that the animations don't work; which effectively breaks the website.

I strongly suspect his companies' network is the root of the problem; however diagnosing this is challenging as he is not a technical user and guiding him through the webkit inspector/console, etc. is not really an option.

Ideally I'd like to be able to 'capture' the network/javascript logs from IE or Chrome so that I can inspect them and attempt to work out what's gone wrong.

**Aside:**

I'm using an off-the-shelf Wordpress theme (http://theme.co/x/) for the site; so I expect the code is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it doesn't seem possible to remotely capture and inspect the network or javascript logs from another machine's browser; there are a number of services that allow you to add automatic error reporting to your javascript code, which you can then inspect to find the root of the problem.

Examples of these are [Errorception](https://errorception.com/) and [Raygun](https://raygun.io/javascript).

As far as I have found, there aren't any similar tools to do so for monitoring network performance / loading specifically- although a similar approach with a custom script to detect if specific items have been loaded could be written.